# How to get an `average` on an eager loading relationship laravel

Tags: laravel

I have the following DB structure:

```
user_talk
- id

user_talk_feedback
- user_talk_id
- rating [from 1 to 5]
```

I have the following relationships:

```php
// on UserTalk model
public function feedbacks(): HasMany
{
  return $this->hasMany(UserTalkFeedback::class);
}
```

I currently have an endpoint that fetches the `UserTalk` and I would like to eager load the average for each `UserTalk`. Is there a way to do it?

So far I have tried:

```
// on UserTalk model
public function averageRating(): HasMany
{
  return $this->hasMany(UserTalkFeedback::class);
}
```

```
$userTalks = UserTalk::with([
  'averageRating' => function ($query) {
    $query->avg('rating');
  }
])
```

But I'm not getting the average of ratings being eager loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try using withAvg():

```
$userTalks = UserTalk::withAvg('feedbacks', 'rating')->paginate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using accessor on the model as follows:

````
```
protected $appends = ['avg_rating'];

public function getAvgRatingAttribute() 
{ 
    return $this->feedbacks->avg('rating');
}
 
 $userTalks = UserTalk::with(['feedbacks'])->get();

```
````